# passing a variable form a loop to a conditional statement

Tags: python

I have got this function in my program.

```
def time(transcriptionFile) :
    ''' This function changes the time values in secs from the transcription file and keeps a list of start time and duration for each phoneme.'''
    with open("transcriptions.txt", "r") as tFile :
        timeList = []
        parameterList = []
        frame = 0.04
        lines = 0
        for line in tFile :
            lines += 1
            for i in range(lines) : 
                i = i * frame
            timeList.append(i)
            li = line.split()
            if li :
                start_time = (int(li[0]) / 10000000.)
                end_time = (int(li[1]) / 10000000.) 
                duration = ((int(li[1]) -int(li[0]))/10000000.)

                poly = poly_coeff(start_time, end_time, i)
                Newton(poly, parameterList)
```

I want to use `i` as an argument in `poly_coeff`. The number of times this function is called is the number of lines in the file. And `i` is increasing with each line. So when the function is called for the first time the first `i` value should should be passed as argument then second time the second `i` value should be passed and so on.

I have certainly done it wrong here I can see but can't figure out how to do it in a right way. Also I guess too much is going on inside a single function. Is it better to split it? But everything is to do with opening the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the line number then you should do

```
poly = poly_coeff(start_time, end_time, lines)
```

If you want to use line number * frame
then do

```
poly = poly_coeff(start_time, end_time, lines * frame)
```

I dont know what you are trying to do with

```
for i in range(lines) : 
    i = i * frame
```

Comment: yes, I could have done this. I should have a list of lines * frame so I had used the for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`i` is only in scope within the for loop. Add a declaration before it so you have access to it later.

```
<snip>
for line in tFile :
            lines += 1
            i = 0
            for i in range(lines) : 
                i = i * frame
<snip>
```

... and yes, I vote for more functional programming; break it out a bit to make it more readable.

Comment: This is actually incorrect, loops do not create a new scope and any names created in the loop are usable after.

Comment: @F.J I thought so too, until I tried a cut down version of his code and it failed with a variable uninitialized error.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**: It looks like you might actually have an indentation error, did you intend to have everything starting with `timelist.append(i)` inside of the loop with `i`?  That would make more sense.

```
        ...
        for i in range(lines): 
            i = i * frame
            timeList.append(i)
            li = line.split()
            if li :
                start_time = (int(li[0]) / 10000000.)
                end_time = (int(li[1]) / 10000000.) 
                duration = ((int(li[1]) -int(li[0]))/10000000.)

                poly = poly_coeff(start_time, end_time, i)
                Newton(poly, parameterList)
```

If the indentation is correct, then I don't think that for loop with `i` is doing what you think it is, here is an example of what is going on:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...   print "before", i
...   i = i * 0.04
...   print "after", i
... 
before 0
after 0.0
before 1
after 0.04
before 2
after 0.08
>>> print i
0.08
```

So basically, after the loop `i` is equivalent to `(lines-1)*frame`.  You modify `i` during each iteration of the loop but it is set back to the next number in the range at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: I need to make a list of increasing i values as well therefore I used it and it was giving me the proper values. Thanks